# Single processes on separate machines vs multithreading on a single machine with cores equal to number of single CPU machines

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's assume that there is a Java program that creates image thumbnails. All cloud providers offer VMs with 1 up to N vCPU virtual machines nodes (VMs).

What would be the advantages and/or disadvantages or running several single-threaded JVM processes each on a single 1 vCPU node vs running one multi-threaded JVM process on a multi-vCPU machine, with the processes number on single vCPU equal to the threads running in the single JVM process?

To give a more precise example:

4 VM nodes each has a 1-vCPU and running single-threaded JVM process that is processing image (this could be anything else)

VS

1 VM node that has 4-vCPU and running multi-threaded JVM process with exact 4 threads each one is doing the exact same task as the single-threaded process above.

Comment: Sounds like you are comparing cluster computing vs. _[SMP architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing)_, but don't overlook the middle way: _[NUMA architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

First, let's assume that the individual threads do not share any Java resources, i.e., don't all synchronize on some lock. They are completely independent.

Second, let's assume for a second that you **aren't using virtual CPUs**, but actual dedicated servers with either 1 CPU or 4 CPUs.

How would the two approaches compete for resources?

#### 4 x 1 CPU, 1 thread

- Each node has its own dedicated IO hardware, so in essence, 4x the IO capacity
- Each node only has one process using its own memory and its own garbage collector
- Because we only have one thread, we hardly have any context switches

#### 1 x 4 CPU, 4 threads

- The 4 threads share the IO hardware, which could lead to contingencies (compared to the other solution), i.e. IO-wait times
- The memory is shared, so if the garbage collector encounters stop the world events (they rarely do these days), *all* threads are blocked. Depending on the GC, this *could* be a bottleneck
- Because we have four threads, we do have context switches all the time. How much this affects performance depends on the JVMs ability to keep all data local to a CPU, i.e., pin threads to a CPU.

Now **with virtual CPUs** some of these differences may disappear. E.g. IO capacity may be identical, because all four virtual nodes may be on one physical machine, just like the one node scenario using 4 virtual CPUs. Garbage collector contention is probably still lower in the 4 vCPUs scenario. Regarding context switches, the question is probably, whether switching between VMs is as cheap as switching between threads. Again, the ability to pin processes/threads to a given physical CPU may be the deciding factor.

To summarize, I don't think you get around benchmarking this. So my advice is to try to learn as much as possible about your infrastructure (so you know what you are measuring) and then run some experiment.

Also, this is something you haven't asked, but there is a cost attached to running both solutions. Administrative overhead/cost is certainly lower when running the multi-threaded solution. On the other hand, running multiple VMs is more robust, because it's not fatal when one VM dies—you still have 3 left running.

Comment: Thanks, a great answer indeed! I would wait a little for other answers, though I think this would be the best but still.

Comment: Cool. I'm actually curious what other people think, too.